# ItemCommand event doesn't fire with repeater control in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a masterpage that  a repeater is inside it that has an imagebutton . but the ItemCommand event doesn't fire with repeater control in master page. please help me.

here is my code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage"  %>

<asp:repeater ID="Repeater1"   runat="server"  OnItemCommand="Repeater1_I">
   <ItemTemplate>

        <div class="product">
            <a title="Details" href="#">  <img id="Img1"  alt="" src='<%# Eval("image") %>' runat="server" class="img-zoom"  /> </a>

            <p><%# Eval("Pname") %></p> 
            <br />
             <asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  class="buttonclass"    ImageUrl="~/css/images/img1.png"  visible="true"   CommandName="ADD" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Pid") %>' />

        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = adsource;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}


protected void Repeater1_I(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ADD")
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post full code of your design source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `Repeater.ItemCommand`, try using `ImageButton.Click` event.

```
<asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  class="buttonclass"    
    ImageUrl="~/css/images/img1.png"  visible="true"   
    CommandName="ADD" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Pid") %>'
    OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

And Code:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton b = sender as ImageButton;
    var arg = b.CommandArgument;
}
```

Comment: You can't make individual events for all controls if there will be multiple controls ahead. `ItemCommand` is used for bubbling up the events of child controls.

Comment: Most likely because of this **if (Page.IsPostBack { return; }**

Comment: tnx for your responce, but i change it to :   if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
        {
         

          
            Repeater1.DataSource = adsource;
            Repeater1.DataBind();} but does not work

Comment: When you click the button, does it make a postback ?

Comment: Javascript related error. Check jQuery and javascript in your code. The browser Console window maybe useful to view errors

Comment: Don't forget best answer *_^

Comment: but how enable this button inside a repeater when js code had disable its postback?